# iOS AFNetworking where to place setWillSendRequestForAuthenticationChallengeBlock on operation

Tags: ios, afnetworking

im using AFNetworking 2, how to set setWillSendRequestForAuthenticationChallengeBlock for sending a certificate on challenge?

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", API_URL_ROOTV1, API_URL_HUBA];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[operation setWillSendRequestForAuthenticationChallengeBlock:^(NSURLConnection *connection, NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *challenge) {

}];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

}];

[operation start];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#define _AFNETWORKING_PIN_SSL_CERTIFICATES_
```

in the file where I tried to call `setWillSendRequestForAuthenticationChallengeBlock`:

I understood that cocoapods already did the #define in Pods-prefix.pch and did not expect that it should be defined again.

it may help u..